# How to fit two or more datasets with different occurence for regression

Tags: r, regression, time-series, excel

I want to run a regression in R with different datasets.
The question is whether stock performance (daily log return) is influenced by factors like interest rates (the one set by fed or ECB), size of the board of directors (e.g. has been long 7 and then switches to 8) and whether there is an audit committee or not (binary, `1` or `0`).

I guess in theory I could just add the interest rate, size of board, etc. to the daily log returns – meaning the interest rate stays fixed for 80 days and then suddenly switches to a new value. However, because this is a large dataset of 10y daily log returns, and I just cannot figure out how to do it automatically in Excel, I am wondering whether it is possible to do that in R or to run a regression on the different data sets. Note: every dataset has a corresponding date.

Since 2 days ago, I've been searching the web but cannot find anything which solves my problem, so your help is really appreciated. If you have any links to papers or the like, it would be totally sufficient :) Although I did find a few papers on that topic, they were cutting-edge theory, which is way too complicated for me.
Thank you!

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to ask questions about the papers on the topic that you found and couldn't understand, in case you want help with those too.

Comment: Oh ok! Didn't thought this would help. Actually, I do not have them anymore but try to find them. Thanks